# Tkinter bind button work incorrectly when hovering

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter-button

Why my Tkinter bind buttons work incorrectly?
When I go on the start button with the mouse, about button will change!
[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKrER.png)

This is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Panel(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # window config
        self.title('test')
        self.geometry('300x300')
        self.configure(bg='#2b2e37')
 
   
    def btns(self, x, y, text, bg, fg):
        def on_enter(ctx):
            self.btn['background'] = fg
            self.btn['foreground'] = bg
        def on_leave(ctx):
            self.btn['background'] = bg
            self.btn['foreground'] = fg

        
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text=text, bg=bg, fg=fg, activebackground=fg, activeforeground=bg, border=0, width=42, height=2)
        self.btn.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
        self.btn.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)
        self.btn.place(x=x, y=y)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Panel()
    window.btns(0, 190, 'S T A R T', '#2b2e37', '#56fc03')
    window.btns(0, 230, 'A B O U T', '#2b2e37', '#f5ec42')
    window.mainloop()
```

I think it's for my oop code, I wrote this simply and worked correctly.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Please ensure you've posted all of your code. It looks like you're missing a line containing `class Panel` and perhaps some others?

Comment: You create exactly one instance of `Panel`, and that instance has exactly one attribute named `btn`.  You're storing both Buttons in that attribute; the second one overwrites the first.

Comment: Tnx for your help but is any way to write it shorter? look at my answer @jasonharper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button on which the event occurs is passed to the event handlers in the `ctx` parameter in the `widget` attribute, so you can use that instead of `self.btn`:

```py
    def btns(self, x, y, text, bg, fg):
        def on_enter(ctx):
            ctx.widget['background'] = fg
            ctx.widget['foreground'] = bg
        def on_leave(ctx):
            ctx.widget['background'] = bg
            ctx.widget['foreground'] = fg
```

The problem with using `self.btn` in place of `ctx.widget` in these event handlers is that the second time you call `btns`, `self.btn` is replaced with the second button, so the event handlers you added to the first button end up making changes to the second button.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code by writing separately for each button.

New code:

```py
    def btns(self):
        def on_enter1(ctx):
            self.btn1['background'] = '#56fc03'
            self.btn1['foreground'] = '#2b2e37'
        def on_leave1(ctx):
            self.btn1['background'] = '#2b2e37'
            self.btn1['foreground'] = '#56fc03'
        def on_enter2(ctx):
            self.btn2['background'] = '#f5ec42'
            self.btn2['foreground'] = '#2b2e37'
        def on_leave2(ctx):
            self.btn2['background'] = '#2b2e37'
            self.btn2['foreground'] = '#f5ec42'

        
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(self, text='S T A R T', bg='#2b2e37', fg='#56fc03', activebackground='#56fc03', activeforeground='#2b2e37', border=0, width=42, height=2)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text='A B O U T', bg='#2b2e37', fg='#f5ec42', activebackground='#f5ec42', activeforeground='#2b2e37', border=0, width=42, height=2)
        self.btn1.bind('<Enter>', on_enter1)
        self.btn1.bind('<Leave>', on_leave1)
        self.btn2.bind('<Enter>', on_enter2)
        self.btn2.bind('<Leave>', on_leave2)
        self.btn1.place(x=0, y=190)
        self.btn2.place(x=0, y=230)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Panel()
    window.label()
    window.btns()
    window.mainloop()
```